# Burninate [class]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I think [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) is too broad to be useful. The metric I always use is:

> How can one be an expert in [tag]?

You can't be. You can be an expert in Object Oriented programming, maybe... I just don't see how it really adds value over a more descriptive tag.

Questions from [the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does describe the contents, but only in a very vague way.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes. I suppose this is a strike against.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

This is the big one: quoting the rules again: *if the tag is superfluous on the vast majority of questions where it is used, then it should go.* I really don't see what it adds to any of these questions. All object oriented languages have the concept of a "class", but most people are not going to be seeing out questions about Java classes AND C# classes AND python classes AND PHP classes etc.

> Note that it's also worth checking the number of followers at this stage, mostly as a sanity-check:

It only has 300 followers. Better tags with a similar number of questions (like [code-igniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-igniter) and [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell)) have more like 4000 followers.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Well, sort of, it means the same concept across all the different languages, but, again, a Java class is different than a PHP class and so forth.

Comment: What about questions about class design in languages where OOP is allowed, but optional?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think the tag can stay. It *does* add meaningful information to a post.

The tag helps to classify questions to specific subject areas within a language; [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) is, to me, meaningful. Python is not a pure OO language, so how to define classes and how they behave is a distinct subject area, setting it apart from [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) or [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) questions, for example.

If [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) is not useful, then there are a few more tags that we'd clear out, including [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), [tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tuple), [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list), [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method), [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/module), etc. etc.

Comment: I completely disagree that things like [tag:string] and [tag:method] would go under the same reasoning as eliminating [tag:class]. Class is a container that encapsulates most code (all code in languages like C# and Java). But [tag:string] is a much narrower focus, as is [tag:method].

Comment: @durron597: that depends entirely on the programming language. In Python classes are optional (though highly recommended). Methods are bound functions on instances, so a distinct concept from functions, and to me have the *exact same level* in usefulness.

Comment: As someone who most often peruses the Python tag, I completely agree with this. Having the `class` tag on questions is very useful when it comes to identifying what kind of question a question will be. Were tags like this to be removed, as Martijn said, we'd basically be stripped down to the `Python` tag and the version-specific tags. Tags like this are still very useful for sorting through question types.

Comment: Ruby has a class called "Class". It's probably notable enough for a tag of some sort.

Answer (score 10):

The key point of the tag description is:

> A template for creating new objects that describes the common state(s) and behavior(s)

In pure OO languages - then yes, I can see (somewhat - but not massively), how it could be considered redundant, but in multi-paradigm languages they're optional and for those languages [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) adds value and an *at a glance* idea of the focus of the question. **It should stay**.