# Should we do a cleanup of tags related to TypeScript concepts?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

It seems like tag names about TS concepts follow the `typescript-*` prefix pattern:

[typescript-decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-decorator)
[typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics)
[typescript-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-types)
[typescript-declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-declarations)
[typescript-definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-definitions)
[typescript-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-class)
[typescript-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-namespace)

ATTOW, they have several issues in common:

1. Most (except for [typescript-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-class), which has a basic wiki and an excerpt) lack an excerpt *and* a wiki.
2. Most (except for [typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics), which has over 1K questions) have a low number of questions (under 100).
3. All of them have a low (under 10) number of watchers (even the [typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics) tag).
4. All of them can be (and frequently are) substituted by builder ("constructor", "lego" - choose your poison) tags as for the most part these concepts are not TS-specific:

   1. [typescript-decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-decorator) -> [[typescript] + [decorator]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+decorator) (~300 questions)
   2. [typescript-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-generics) -> [[typescript] + [generics]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+generics) (1.5K questions)
   3. [typescript-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-types) -> [[typescript] + [types]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+types) (~1.9K questions)
   4. [typescript-declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-declaration) -> [[typescript] + [declaration]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+declaration) (70 questions)
   5. [typescript-definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-definitions) -> [[typescript] + [definition]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+definition) (~40 questions)
   6. [typescript-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-class) -> [[typescript] + [class]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+class) (~600 questions)
   7. [typescript-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript-namespace) -> [[typescript] + [namespaces]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript+namespaces) (~150 questions)

   Unfortunately, some of these tags suffer from problem #1: lack of wiki/excerpt: 
   1. [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/definition) has a particularly "useful" one, and some lack a TS-specific section
   2. [namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespaces) wiki lists only PHP, Python, .NET, and C++ examples
   3. [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics) omits the notion of TS generics as well
   4. [declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declaration) only has an excerpt

   Also, some might view [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class), [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespace) and similar as [too generic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300571/what-is-the-point-of-generic-language-agnostic-tags-about-basic-programming-con?noredirect=1&lq=1) (although a request to remove [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) has been [declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290894/burninate-class?noredirect=1&lq=1) before), which brings extra complexity to the issue at hand.

Given #4, we have two diverging tag naming paths that will be progressively harder to reconcile as time passes. On the other hand, the existing tags are not in their best shape, as well as being not very popular (see #3).

So, the question is:

> what do you think would be the best way to deal with these tags (and should anything be done in the first place)?

Initial thoughts on actions that can be taken:

- Retag `typescript-*` to separate tags, expand the relevant wikis with TS info
- Retag separate tags to `typescript-*` and create their wikis/excerpts
- If choosing to retag to separate, `typescript-*` ones can be made synonyms of the former

---

As a separate concern, there is an astray [typeguards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeguards) tag which, despite its generic naming, is exclusively used by questions about TS type guards. Seems like it could be `typescript-*` prefixed for consistency.

Found another orphan tag: [mapped-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapped-types). Used exclusively by questions about TS mapped types, very low number of watchers (3 ATTOW).

Another one, [conditional-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-types), fares slightly better with a basic [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/conditional-types/info) and excerpt. It is slightly ambiguous: at least 3 questions use it [for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-types+-typescript) questions, so it either needs to be inlined with `typescript-*` prefix pattern or probably made language-agnostic (like [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics)).

And another tag is [index-signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/index-signature). No ambiguity found, it just lacks [wiki and except](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/index-signature/info). Given the above, at least 4 more tags do not follow the `typescript-*` prefix while being TS-exclusive in usage.

---

An aside: there is also a problem with [narrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/narrowing) and [type-narrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-narrowing), which are basically the same tag used for the concept common to multiple languages, TypeScript included. Likely needs a standalone proposal to merge.

Comment: Probably duplicate of "excel + vba" vs. "excel-vba" eternal battle...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - as far as I recall it [was resolved after all](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177/11407695) (albeit not without a lot of drama during the dispute), wasn't it? I hope this will not lead to a new tag war... Honestly, I will be happy if this at least results in some of the tags getting wikis/excerpts.

Comment: I guess I mixing timeframes in my head - I think I remember more posts after that for people going back and adding them again... but it very well could be other way around in timeline. (I personally absolutely don't care about tag descriptions/wiki as no one reads them to my observations and this information is well hidden in the site's UI to worry enough about it. The only usage so far is ban people for poor edits of those :) )

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - seems like all `*-vba` tags [are dead now](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=vba&starts=1) at least. Agreed that excerpts/wikis aren't really useful (I am still unsure, though, of whether no one reads them because 99% of them do not have useful info or vice versa) - just trying to find something positive in case the ultimate goal flops. I like your notion of usefulness, though :)

Comment: I don't see any point on having a decorator, generics, class, definitions, etc. tags. Every tag should be able to function as the only tag on the question, these do not. If something should be done, just merging them into typescript is a viable solution.

Comment: "*Convert [[tag:typescript-decorator]] to [[tag:typescript]] + [[tag:decorator]]*" - I don't agree with that one. There have been many versions of the ECMAScript decorators proposal floating around, and the current typescript implementation has its own peculiarities that would make it worth distinguishing them from other decorator versions. Also [[tag:decorator]] has the problem of referring to the GoF decorator pattern, not to the syntactical element (although used for both), so that does need some disambiguation.

Comment: @Bergi - aren't decorators an implementation of the decorator pattern as they modify the behaviour of a class/method/function without mutating it? That said, I agree with disambiguating it (after all, we have [tag:observer-pattern], [tag:factory-pattern], [tag:strategy-pattern], etc. Oh, we have one already: [tag:decorator-pattern]! Which means that there may be a separate issue of retagging some of the questions. Also worth noting that other decorator-related tags seem to follow the `<language>-decorators` pattern consistently, so it makes sense to leave the [tag:typescript-decorator] be.

Comment: I don't understand why Meta posts about tags get so hung-up on missing tag wiki's and then start calling it "an issue". I can solve that "issue" by putting in each wiki *Oleg didn't had time to write a decent wiki yet, give it 6 to 8 weeks* . If a tag is clear, a wiki isn't a pre-requisite. If the tag is used wrongly then a wiki can help but still isn't mandatory to get a tagging problem "solved"

Comment: @rene, frankly, I did not (and do not) consider missing wikis and excerpts a major problem, but when listing the tags to discuss, I think it is diligent to provide info on what they lack (and also give these omissions a bit more visibility). Please note that each listing here talks about usage and naming first and foremost.

Comment: I'm one of the two watches on `mapped-types`. The main `typescript` tag can get really polluted with questions about code that happens to be written in Typescript rather than questions about Typescript types. The feature-specific tags help myself and others find interesting questions. `typescript-types` should probably be merged with `typescript-typings` or vice-versa. I submitted a wiki for `typescript-generics` a few days ago but it is still awaiting peer review. Here's a new tag with only 6 questions: [`variadic-tuple-types`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-tuple-types)

Comment: There are certain terms for features which are only used in TS and some that are used in other languages.  A good chunk of the questions in [discriminated-union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discriminated-union) are about TS but more are about f#.  [conditional-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-types) is overwhelmingly TS with 3 questions about c# and 157 about TS.  [union-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/union-types) is majority TS but some Scala.

Comment: I'm more annoyed by version tags than by feature tags.  People are still using [typescript2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript2.0)

Comment: @LindaPaiste - re:mapped-types. I was the second watcher :) Now there are 3. Feature-specific types do indeed help filter questions to leave questions that are guaranteed to be  of relevant content as opposed to the main [tag:typescript] tag. Re: wikis - yeah, mine for [tag:typescript-namespace] is the third week in, but unfortunately, the random nature of the review queue isn't helping. Re: VTT - yeah, saw the tag, wasn't sure if it belongs to the request, since [typescript-variadic-tuple-types] sounds horrifyingly long. Still needs a wiki and an excerpt, though.

Comment: Apparently I submitted `typescript-types` as a potential synonym for `typescript-typings` back in October but no one has voted on it.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript-typings/synonyms

Comment: @LindaPaiste - given how the [tag:typescript-types] is misused (people seem to slap it in a sense that their question is about "types" in a general sense), it would be better off merged into the main tag. It seems way too broad otherwise (like, what types? conditional? generics? recursive? etc). Given the [tag:typescript-typings] was intended to be used for the questions about the older way of adding type definitions and now is grossly misused to denote "anything type-related", it probably warrants a disambiguation request in itself

Comment: My opinion is that the tags should work as the only tag for the question. As described in https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/ From that, `[typescript]+[namespaces]` does not sound like a good option, but the `[typescript]` tag alone should work for fundamentals about the Typescript language  - this is applicable to most options here.